# how to use binding in monodeveop or xamarin?

Tags: c#, binding, monodevelop

i want to use binding control properties in monodevelop .
i can use this code in win form application:

```
button1.DataBindings.Add("Text", textBox1, "Text");
```

how to use this code (or example this) for xamarin or monodevelop C# applications?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik DataBinding is something that belongs with a MVVM pattern. Regular Mono and Xamarin follow the MVC pattern which native Android and iOS also use. As such Mono and regular Xamarin don't support DataBinding.

There is a framework called MvvmCross (probably others too) for Xamarin that enables the MVVM pattern.

But probably better, if you want DataBinding, you really should take a look at Xamarin.Forms. This does allow DataBinding (and a lot more). DataBinding is explained at: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/xaml-for-xamarin-forms/data_binding_basics/